# How to use jquery function in a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use some functionality like a sidepanel to open but using an `<a>` tag.

Could you please help me, below is the code related to it.

HTML

```
<a href="#">Click Me</a>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(function($){
    //open the lateral panel
    $('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.cd-panel').addClass('is-visible');
    });
    //close the lateral panel
    $('.cd-panel').on('click', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is('.cd-panel') || $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close') ) { 
            $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

I want to make use of the above jQuery and use it in my `<a>` tag.

Comment: Do you know the basics of jquery ???? ..... Is this too much basic for SO ?

Comment: You need to wrap the script in a trigger, for example $(document).ready(). jQuery(function($){}) is not a trigger.

Comment: @MCMXCII he is already. That's shorthand

Comment: What is the `tag` that you are referring to?

Comment: @DaniP, no I am very new to jquery.

Comment: @SterlingArcher My bad, had never actually seen this shorthand syntax.

Comment: @MCMXCII yeah that's a shorthand for what you are referring to.

Comment: What element does .cd-btn refer to?

Comment: I have a sidepanel which usually opens with a button, but wanted to use the same with an <a> tag.

Comment: Can't you add the class `.cd-btn`to your a link and the `.cd-panel` to your panel

Comment: You'll need to add class="cd-btn" to the a tag then.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bob_js/xbxsocsj/2/

Comment: The . refers to classes, you don't need to include it in the class name.

Comment: I did add the class but for some reason it is not doing anything when I add a class (.cd-btn) to the tag. So am I missing anything. Like usually I saw some people using <a href="#" onclick="myfunction">

Comment: He means class="cd-btn" not class=".cd-btn". Take out the '.'

Comment: what would be the 'Onclick' function in my case is something I am asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the `click` event to `body` and delegate to `cd-btn`. Adding event handler to element directly [doesn't handle dynamic elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on). The element `cd-btn` is in your pop-up. The pop-up HTML is dynamically injected, so when you attach the event the HTML is probably not present. But you can easily add the handler to `body` and delegate it like:

```
  $('body').on('click', '.cd-btn',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.cd-panel').addClass('is-visible'); 
  });
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  //open the lateral panel
  $('body').on('click', '.cd-btn',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.cd-panel').addClass('is-visible'); 
  });
  //close the lateral panel
  $('.cd-panel').on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('.cd-panel') || $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close')) {
      $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});

$(function() {
  $("#popover-a").popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'click hover',
    delay: {
      show: 50,
      hide: 3500
    },
    content: function() {
      return $('#popover-content-a').html();
    }
  });
  $("#popover-b").popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'click hover',
    delay: {
      show: 50,
      hide: 3500
    },
    content: function() {
      return $('#popover-content-b').html();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.circle-macro {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(68, 104, 125);
  color: white;
  padding: 0 8px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  font-style: italic;
  z-index: 10;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.cd-main-content {
  text-align: center;
}
.cd-main-content .cd-btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #89ba2c;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.no-touch .cd-main-content .cd-btn:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.cd-panel {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0.6s;
  transition: visibility 0s 0.6s;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  z-index: 9;
}
.cd-panel::after {
  /* overlay layer */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s 0.3s;
}
.cd-panel.is-visible {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: visibility 0s 0s;
}
.cd-panel.is-visible::after {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s 0s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s 0s;
  transition: background 0.3s 0s;
}
.cd-panel.is-visible .cd-panel-close::before {
  -webkit-animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
  -moz-animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
  animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
}
.cd-panel.is-visible .cd-panel-close::after {
  -webkit-animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
  -moz-animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
  animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
}
.cd-panel-header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 27px;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -webkit-transition: top 0.3s 0s;
  -moz-transition: top 0.3s 0s;
  transition: top 0.3s 0s;
}
.from-right .cd-panel-header,
.from-left .cd-panel-header {
  top: -50px;
}
.from-right .cd-panel-header {
  right: 0;
}
.from-left .cd-panel-header {
  left: 0;
}
.is-visible .cd-panel-header {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.3s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: top 0.3s 0.3s;
  transition: top 0.3s 0.3s;
}
.cd-panel-container {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: #fafafa;
  border-left: 1px solid #c8cacc;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 70%;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.from-right .cd-panel-container {
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
.from-left .cd-panel-container {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}
.is-visible .cd-panel-container {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Title
</div>
<div class="container">
  <i id="popover-a" class="circle-macro" tabindex="0" data-container="body" data-html="true" data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right">i</i>

  <div id="popover-content-a" class="hidden">
    <div>
      <h6><b>Heading</b></h6>
      <p>Content <a href="#" class="cd-btn">Click Me</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>

  <i id="popover-b" class="circle-macro" tabindex="1" data-container="body" data-html="true" data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right">i</i>

  <div id="popover-content-b" class="hidden">
    <div>
      <h6><b>Heading</b></h6>
      <p>Content <a href="#" class="cd-btn">Click Me</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="cd-panel from-right">
  <header class="cd-panel-header">
    <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close">Close</a>
  </header>
  <div class="cd-panel-container">


CD PANEL
  </div>
  <!-- cd-paneCD PANELl-container -->
</div>
<!-- cd-panel -->
```